# How to scroll the collection view horizontal with header

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have collectionview with header.

[This is  the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O24nI.png)

In this, i have display the questions in the UICollectionReusableView as  header and answers in the collectionviewcell.
So the image is this way.But i need to scroll the collectionview horizontal only.

But that time it will become as :-

[This is the header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOVEl.png)

[This is the cell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3UBs.png)

But i need this in the first screen header and its answers. when user scroll it then need show 2nd question in header and its answers. How to implement it?

currently my code is as below:-

```
extension NH_DummyDataViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

        return self.questionViewModel.numberOfSections()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = verticalCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NH_Headercell", for: indexPath)as!  NH_Headercell

    //    cell.options.text = "hello"

    //    let optionModel = self.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

        cell.setReviewData(reviews:self.questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))


        return cell
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {


        let  firstheader: NH_QuestionHeaderCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "NH_QuestionHeaderCell", for: indexPath ) as! NH_QuestionHeaderCell


        firstheader.setReviewData(reviews:questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:indexPath.section))

        return firstheader
    }
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension NH_DummyDataViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {


        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: How to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

Set Collection view scroll direction Horizontal and set paging

```
yourCollectionview.pagingEnabled = true
```

Comment: scrolling horizontal but header and cells not displaying together.how to implement that..As it will show first header then after scrolling it will shows the collectionviewcell.But i need to display together.How to implement

Comment: currently my code has update .please check...how to scroll the problem.

Comment: You want header with every cell. Header is common for all cell, its not set to each cell. If you want header view with each cell then add new view with label in cell and update header label value.